# im getting a segmentation fault when i use strcat.please tell me what is going wrong

Tags: c

```
void rpn(char*text)
{static int j=0;
char st[10];
char str[80]="";
int i;
int n=strlen(text);
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{printf("enter\n");
    if(text[i]=="(")
    {
       continue; 
    }
    else if(text[i]=='+'||text[i]=='*'||text[i]=='-'||text[i]=='/'||text[i]=='^')
    {
      st[j]=text[i];
      printf("%c\n",st[j]);
      j++;
    }
    else if(text[i]==')')
    {
       strcat(str,st[j]);
       printf("%c\n",str);
        j--;
    }
    else
    {   
        printf("yay\n");
       strcat(str,text[i]);
       //strcat(str,'\0');
       printf("%c\n",str);
    }
}
if(st[j]!="null")
{int k;
    for(k=j;k>=0;k--)
    {
        strcat(str,st[j]);
    }
}

}
int main()
{
printf("find ex\n");
char texts[]="((a+t)*((b+(a+c))^(c+d)))";
rpn(texts);
return 0;
}
```

Output:
find ex
enter
yay
Segmentation fault 
it prints yay but when it has to copy letter "a" from text[i] to str it shows segmentation fault .
i dont understand why i have tried everything allocated extra space etc nothing seems to work.

Comment: Fyi, `if (st[j] != "null")` is not correct (it will always be true). You're comparing a single `char` against the base address of a string literal. Likewise for `text[i] == "("` earlier, but there it will always be false. And obviously `strcat(str, st[j])` is wrong; the second argument should be a pointer, not a `char`. I think you need to review the string section of whatever book/tutorial/class you're reviewing.

Comment: strcat(str,st[j]);
This is not correct. The second argument has type char in your call and it should be char*. The signature of strcat is

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)

Comment: @WhozCraig can you please recommend where should i go through the strings section from

Comment: Your code emits a ton of warnings. Fix them.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2) separate code blocks: `if` `for` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  2) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to obtain the same results

Comment: TO help your self, when using any of the C library functions, please read/understand the MAN page for that function, especially the syntax and parameter types

Comment: @user3629249 whats a MAN page ?

Comment: @user3629249 thnx for all your help

Comment: a MAN page is the page of the C manual.  Each page is (typically) for a single C library function.   Using a search engine, search for: `man page for read`  The resulting search results page will have entries for the OS `read` command and the C library `read()` function.  All the C library functions can be researched via similar search critieria

Comment: searching for: `contents of string.h in c` will display a search results page and one of the entries in that search results page contains all the functions exposed in the header file: `string.h` and a link to each MAN page for each function

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems in your code

> static int j=0;

why *j* is static while it is used as an index in *st* which is *not* static

> if(text[i]=="(")

is invalid, you compare a character with a string, the behavior is undefined

> strcat(str,st[j]);

is invalid, the second argument is a character rather than a string

> printf("%c\n",str);

is invalid, the format waits for an *int* (being the code of a character to print it)  but the argument is a string

> strcat(str,text[i]);

is invalid, the second argument is a character rather than a string

> if(st[j]!="null")

is invalid, you compare a character and a string, the behavior is undefined

> strcat(str,st[j]);

is invalid, the second argument is a character rather a string

Note also out of the previous problems there is protection to avoid to read/write out of the arrays through an invalid index (too large for the two arrays, or also negative for *st* in case the expression has too mush ')')

Probably *st* must be an array of `char*` rather than an array of *char* ( to change its type is not enough to have the code correct )

---

It seems you want to parse the expression, but what results you expect ?

Comment: my answer should be this at+bac++cd+^* . can u tell me what can i do to add a character to str if cthe condition is met

Comment: @user10598529 so you want to make the postfix expression from the infix one, for that you have to extract the elements but also to get into account the priority of the operators, there is nothing about that in your code